# selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver' has no attribute 'ChromeOptions in Python Robotframework

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying write function in python to avoid SSL certiicate error and chrome unpacked extension. But I am keep getting an issue in ChromeOptions.

Error :  module 'selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver' has no attribute 'ChromeOptions

Library imported

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def open2browser():
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)   
    chromeOptions.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')  
    EXE_PATH = r'C:\ABC\chromedriver.exe'  
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=EXE_PATH, options=chromeOptions)  
    driver.get('www.google.com')  
    driver.maximize_window()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root cause of this issue is the below import.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import webdriver
```

your `webdriver.Chrome` is using the import from this and it's causing the issue.  Ideally you just need `from selenium import webdriver` import rest are not required in this case.

Comment: Problem fixed. I delete from selenium.webdriver.chrome import webdriver. That solve the issue.

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if this/any answer is/was helpful to you. [Upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the answer helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers